# Equatorial Scale

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, scale

I have seen Equatorial Scale written along with the RF on the World Map in many Atlases, for eg., "Equatorial Scale 1:95 000 000". What does this Equatorial Scale mean and what is the significance of writing it in Atlases and Individual maps?

Answer (score 3):

The scale is not a constant on map projections. For local map it is not an issue because the change in scale is so small that it is below the precision of the drawing, but for World map there can be huge difference when you change latitude (obviously, in a Mercator projection, the same distance near the pole is not equivalent to the distance near the equator). For correctness, the scale value is therefore provided for a specific location, and the equator is very convenient.

As a remark to the comment, the best global maps that I know use a scale graphic instead of a scale bar (see example below). On the other hand, some projection have a constant scale along meridians, therefore a vertical scale bar could be correct in these case.

[image]

Comment: The real question is why providing a scale that's false everywhere on the map but along the equator...